Failed when call to Azure Function Apps on Azure Data Factory
I cannot call Functions in Azure Data Factory.
Every time I try, it shows that error:
Input Payload is invalid, validation result - '["Connector or activity name: xxxx_function, connector or activity type: Azure Function, error: The stream was already consumed. It cannot be read again."]'
This issue appeared in today morning. In the previous days, there are no problem.
I used Python for my Function Apps.
I tried  : - renew Function key in Functions App and refill this value in Linked service to Azure Funtion.
But it isn't working.
I would be so grateful if you would be willing to help. Thanks <3


It is difficult to comprehend with the details provided, however, a common sense approach is to look at the error and see what it says. For me, you are trying to consume/ intend to consume a piece of information that is not available / or not available in within the execution context. E.g: something like a non-readable/seekable stream or stream is now off context.

I encountered a similar issue a few hours ago, but in my case, it was with Azure Data Factory Script Activity rather than Azure Functions. All of the linked services that were supposed to connect to various databases suddenly stopped working, which caused multiple pipeline failures.
It was some Azure issue and we raised a support ticket, but it was resolved in the meantime.

I had the same thing happen to me @ntomazin. Everything was working and then just started failing with that message.

Try to check the formatting of input payload. I have created a default V2 HTTP triggered python function and calling it from ADF.
You can refer to this documentation as well.
My pipeline looks like below

Input payload-
{
    "functionName": "http_trigger1",
    "body": {
        "name": "Afreen"
    },
    "headers": {},
    "method": "POST"
}


Output -
{
    "Response": "Hello, Afreen. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.",
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime (East US)",
    "executionDuration": 2,
    "durationInQueue": {
        "integrationRuntimeQueue": 0
    },
    "billingReference": {
        "activityType": "ExternalActivity",
        "billableDuration": [
            {
                "meterType": "AzureIR",
                "duration": 0.016666666666666666,
                "unit": "Hours"
            }
        ]
    }
}

References -
Error in Calling Azure Function Apps from Azure Data Factory (devcodef1.com).
